# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customWidgets'

Tags: python, tkinter, modulenotfounderror

I'm getting this error while I try to run the main.py file (using python GUI Tkinter)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doVLN.png). Could someone provide me a solution to this?

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code or errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the error. It would be best if you could also provide a [mcve]. That being said, the error means exactly what it says: you're trying to import something and python can't find it.

Comment: Can you please post the code you are trying to run? And, as @BryanOakley said, produce a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the customWidgets package installed? I don't see any package named that on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). 
Or if it is a python file made by you, are you sure you placed it in the right directory (the default python packages directory or the directory you're working in)?